# Windows route selection and "route print -6" vs "netsh interface ipv6 show route"

Tags: windows-10, routing, ipv6, netsh, multicast

So I'm using Windows 10 and I need to redirect some IPv6 multicast traffic to a specific interface (a USB-Ethernet adapter to be more specific).

By default all multicast traffic is going to my WiFi connection (verified using WireShark). If I disable the WiFi interface, I can observe the multicast traffic in question going to the USB-Ethernet adapter.

**`route print -6`** gives the following output (only relevant networks shown here):

```
 Active Routes:
 If Metric Network Destination      Gateway
  1   331  ff00::/8                 On-link
 14   286  ff00::/8                 On-link
 15   257  ff00::/8                 On-link
```

...and **`netsh interface ipv6 show route`** shows the following (only relevant networks shown here):

```
Publish  Type      Met  Prefix                    Idx  Gateway/Interface Name
-------  --------  ---  ------------------------  ---  ------------------------
No       System    256  ff00::/8                    1  Loopback Pseudo-Interface 1
No       System    256  ff00::/8                   14  Wi-Fi
No       System    256  ff00::/8                   15  ethernet_usb
```

- The metrics are different in both outputs (`netsh` output shows 256
  for all interfaces and `route` shows values like 331, 286 and 257).
  What do each of these values mean?
- Secondly, how do I change the order here so that all traffic for
  `ff00::/8` is routed through interface 15 (ethernet_usb). I would
  prefer not to delete the route completely from the Wi-Fi interface
  but changing metric through adapter settings didn't seem to have any
  effect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, the **route print -6**  command show the **route metric**

Second, the **netsh interface ipv6 show route** show **gateway metric**

And, **route metric = interface metric + gateway metric**

In addition, you can use the command to see what the interface metric is by **netsh interface ip show address**.

Comment: Thank you for this explanation, I've wondered how this worked for a while now. The interface metric used is actually powershell "Get-NetIPInterface", which shows both ipv4 and ipv6 interface metrics. The metric in "netsh interface ip show address" seems to be different on my system, and is not in the equation.